How do I deal with a coworker whose poor work quality is impacting my personal life and career growth?
I’m a Senior Frontend Engineer at a subsidiary of a major European grocery delivery company, and right now, So right now we are building a new version of our core product. We started this project over a year and a half ago with a team of six devs, but by January, I was left with just one other senior developer due of layoffs. Initially, we moved slowly, focusing on simpler features, but positive user feedback made us to ramp up and complete the application for migration of our entire user base.
As we dove into more complex features, I realised that the code quality of one of the other senior FE engineer is really abysmal. I raised this issue to him during code reviews and gave him some suggestions to improve his code quality, he would agree to some of those suggestions, would fix the issues and than in the next PR I would see same problems propping up again. I found myself refactoring his code repeatedly, only to watch him revert to his messy habits, creating a frustrating cycle. Each time I tried to build on his work, I was met with spaghetti code that forced me into major refactoring, which often broke other features.
At this point I am literally banging my head into the wall daily, we are now taking twice the time we commit to deliver a feature and that too is also not bug free. This chaos is spilling into my personal life. I’m clocking 11-12 hour a day including weekends, Along with work I was also preparing for my GMAT exam. Now due to increase work pressure I am unable to keep up with my studies and it is now sort of exacerbating of my anxiety and depressive symptoms along with some other physical conditions I have. I feel stagnant, and overwhelmed, with my growth stifled. I’ve considered resigning to focus on my studies, but financially, that wouldn’t; be viable. Moreover I feel being jobless is only going to make me more anxious and depressive  I’m at a loss for how to move forward.

What exactly makes you work 11 hours and on weekends? Can you just deliver less instead?

Have you discussed any of this with your manager in the past 9 months, and if not, why not?

Their work should not affect your personal life. Tell management what you are waiting for, then let them fail unless management asks you to close the gap; if they go ask you need to decide whether you want to do the additional work and earn an "exceeds" performance rating or decline and get "meets requirements, reluctantly."

Why are you working extra hours? Are you being paid for those extra hours? Why don’t you look for a different job and only after being successful resign?

Correction: "if they do ask".

I've been working extra hours because:
My manager asked me to, although it was verbal, not written.
I need to fix issues from another developer's work, which requires additional coding and testing.
I'm not being compensated for this. While I've considered leaving, I don't want to divert my focus from GMAT prep to interview prep. Additionally, I need strong letters of recommendation for my MBA applications, and my manager and CTO could provide valuable ones
I've raised concerns about the quality of the other developer's work, but my manager prioritized speed over quality

Somebody cut the budget (Layoffs). It isn't your responsibility to make up the difference. Do the best you can, have pride in your work. But two things to remember 1.) Don't work to the point of burn-out. 2.) Don't cover somebody else's sloppy work. I am not saying to disengage. But don't put the world on your shoulders. Example: it is one thing to mentor versus having to fix somebody's code over and over.

@anonymous_dev - "I need to fix issues from another developer's work, which requires additional coding and testing." - Have you told your manager how many hours you are spending fixing code generated by this Senior Frontend Engineer?  Are you the only one working these additional hours? You need to make the problem, not your problem, unless it's your job to fix the problem. "I'm not being compensated for this." - Stop working for free If it really has become a team of two, yourself and this Senior FE, then you need to inform your manager of the situation. Stop working for free

Also, if you really are "literally banging my head into the wall daily", also stop doing that...

To be clear, your coworker's poor work quality is not impacting your personal life and career growth. Your choice to work 11-12 hours a day including weekends is doing that. And you're right, it has to stop. Make different choices.
I know, your employer's expectations are keeping you from making different choices. So sit with this: it is your employer's expectations that are impacting your personal life and career growth. Set aside hopes of fixing your coworker or getting them to work shoulder to shoulder with you so you can get into the graduate program of your choice. Your priorities are not the coworker's priorities and frankly, not your manager's either. You say "prioritized speed over quality" and I hear "shipping is a feature" - stuff needs to get done and out the door, and you may or may not be setting the quality bar where it should be, but you're surely not setting it where management wants it.
So here it is. You intend to leave this job after you've got what you want from it. In the mean time, they don't value what you value. When you say that doing things the way you want requires you to work almost double hours, they say "well ok we won't stop you" and kind of shrug. What makes you think doing this will get you the strong letters of recommendation you want?

AD demonstrated a lack of understanding of our priorities and quality standards, told a senior coworker their code was abysmal, overworked towards the point of burnout doing things we said were not needed, broke working code trying to "refactor" it because it was "messy", and complained that our choices were interfering with AD's personal life.

Is that the letter you want?
Breathe. Assess your priorities. Can you work the way they want you to? Producing code that isn't maintainable and won't last long, but gets things done today? Would doing that put your workload back where it belongs? If so, do it. You're not running this company and you won't carry the burden of the messy unmaintainable code later. As you've seen, clean and beautiful code is not free. It has a value, yes, and it also has a cost. Single handedly incurring the cost yourself so that they can reap the value when you're gone is just not a good choice.
If you can't work that way, then you need to work elsewhere. It's not just that putting yourself through this for letters of recommendation isn't worth it (you're anxious and depressed already), it's that it won't work. You and management fundamentally disagree on something pretty important, and you can't even see why they might have a point. You think the CTO is going to be writing a letter about how brilliant you are? I hate to be blunt, but they all think you're wrong. Possibly even headstrong and foolish. If they thought you were admirable and right, they would have told you so and explained why it can't be done the right way on this occasion.

It would significantly help you to set more reasonable expectations for yourself and management. Begin to expand any estimates of work for longer periods of time to give yourself time during the workday only to complete what you promise to deliver.

Initially, we moved slowly, focusing on simpler features

This set an expectation for you, your team and management about what gets delivered and when, probably based on what is visible to the user.
It is unrealistic to sustain the same pace of delivery with a given standard of quality for a codebase that is growing in complexity with a team that has not changed in size or significantly improved in capabilities.
It sounds like you, however, have this expectation and management either has that expectation also, or else you are supporting their belief in this because of your expanded work hours.
Rather than quit, maybe reduce management expectations by telling them to expect more time to deliver your next feature. Be prepared by breaking down the time it has taken you to build other similar features, if you can. Maybe they will "fire" you if you slow down, but probably not. Also, try include time in your estimates for your teammate to fix their own code, as they may not understand what you are doing or saying until they do it themselves. That seems to be the case.
But regardless, if you include your teammate's poor coding into your estimates of effort along with the increased complexity of the codebase, it should naturally result in taking more time to develop features assuming you are not working 11-12 hour days and return to a reasonable workday routine.
Start to reset expectations so that you don't burn out, you deliver a quality product to your employer and you have time to relax or grow personally - including studying for the GMAT.
